# Multi-Store issues with loading some template files/skins

Tags: template, multistore, frontend, store-view

We're having an issue here, where some stores load the store view with Magento defaults (only one of them does this out of 7 of them).

- SetEnvIf for MAGE_RUN_CODE is set in .htaccess based on request domain, then index.php launches the store view.
- base_url and secure_base_url configured in the System settings

All of them are set correctly like the others, but when it comes to loading the template files for one of them, it just reverts to default Magento theme. I cannot understand why it is doing this. Is there something in xml that has been overlooked? We changed all the store codes, and directed domain names to the index.php, and changed all the settings to match in htaccess and Manage Stores, all of the other domains we set up are working fine except one. Where can I check for breakpoints? There are no exceptions being thrown it seems when Magento falls back on the default.

Adding the new store views to the cms home page doesn't work, we either get a 404 (no-route) or an error that there is no cms page set.

Comment: I am asking some info apart from your post, i am created multi-store, using http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-website/. I am using the same theme for both stores, how can i change header and footer for my second store, pls keep in mind same theme. What is the use of symlinks?

Answer (score 4):

Well I found settings in System -> Configuration -> Store View -> Design where I can uncheck the box for Use Website then I set the template folder name in Templates, Skin, and Layout to point it directly to the files. It's just a one word url key value that corresponds to the folder name in app/design/frontend/