# Magento changing store code creates issues in site css loading

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view

I have installed Magento 1.9.2.4 CE for my site. It is a multistore site with two stores, "default" and "business".

Now I for a while changed my "default" store-view's code to something else and reverted back.

But when I open "default" store in my site, it's css doesn't seem to load properly. It's display is all messed up.

Default store: http://kaffemesteren.webexpressen.no/default/

Business store: http://kaffemesteren.webexpressen.no/bedrift/

I already cleared cache and session, still same issue.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6457/multi-store-issues-with-loading-some-template-files-skins?rq=1

Comment: But prior to changing store-code and reverting(changed the default store code back to default) back all was working fine, without needing to change any setting in System >> Configuration >> Store view >> Design, so I want to get back Old scenario, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Web Inspect, the only CSS file that is not loading is the one for your AW Blog. All other stylesheets are loading properly. In fact, it looks like you're using the very same CSS files for both sites.

They both look very similar to me, too.

You may need to clear your browser cache, although that shouldn't matter, either.

Comment: No actually it was "Ultimo" theme thirdparty that was the culprit, it generates the theme-css dynamically according to store-code like `design_default.css` or `bedrift_default.css` and not just this one, but a couple more too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try copy style.css from aw_blog package to 
skin/frontend/base/default/aw_blog/css/style.css
or in yours current skins
skin/frontend/current_package/current_theme/aw_blog/css/style.css